# Trying to get knapsack problem to work without multidimensional arrays

Tags: c#, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I'm trying to do my own implementation of the knapsack algorithm, and I was wondering if it could be done without multidimensional arrays, which is what I see online mostly.

The idea wasn't to make the most optimal one, so I merely used the methods I felt were what could get the job done. (using lists instead of int[])

I feel like i'm close to getting it, but not quite there yet, and I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

The below is fed by a driver function that parses say, the following input (weight:value):

Max

50

10:60,20:100,30:120

Should print 220, and the subset that creates it.

CheckSum returns true if the value, when added is less than or equal to the max weight.

Although, half the code is merely getting and placing the values...

```
 public static bool Knapsack(int W, Dictionary<int, Tuple<int,int>> Items, List<int> numbers)
    {
        List<int> summationValue;
        List<int> subset;
        List<int> summationWeight;
        List<KeyValuePair<int, List<int>>> finalSet = new List<KeyValuePair<int, List<int>>>();

        for (int auto = 0; auto <= Items.Count-1; auto++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Iteration: " + auto);
            int value1 = Items[auto].Item2;
            int weight1 = Items[auto].Item1;
            summationValue = new List<int> { value1 };
            subset = new List<int> { (auto+1) };
            summationWeight = new List<int> { weight1 };
            //Initialize//var currentItem = itemIndex == 0 ? null : items[itemIndex - 1];
            for (int other_nodes = 0; other_nodes <= Items.Count-1; other_nodes++)
            {
                if (other_nodes == auto)
                {
                    other_nodes++;
                }
                int value2 = Items[other_nodes].Item2;
                int weight2 = Items[other_nodes].Item1;
                if (CheckSum(summationWeight, weight2, W))
                {
                    summationValue.Add(value2); 
                    subset.Add(other_nodes+1);
                    summationWeight.Add(weight2);
                    KeyValuePair<int, List<int>> kv = new KeyValuePair<int, List<int>>(summationValue.Sum(), subset);
                    finalSet.Add(kv);
                    break;
                }



            }

            //After all item iteration, print outputs; [Highest value] [Subset] [Weight]
            string printValue = summationValue.Sum().ToString();
            subset.Sort();
            string printWeight = summationWeight.Sum().ToString();

            Console.WriteLine("Highest Value: ");
            Console.WriteLine(printValue);
            Console.WriteLine("Subsets: \n");
            Console.Write("{ ");
            foreach (var i in subset)
            {
                 Console.Write(i + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("}");
            Console.WriteLine("Highest Weight: ");
            Console.WriteLine(printWeight);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("[========================]");
        var pair = finalSet.OrderByDescending(x => x.Key).First();
        var keys = finalSet.Where(kvp => kvp.Key == pair.Key).Select(kvp => kvp.Key).ToArray();
        var fkey = keys.Max();
        Console.WriteLine(fkey);
        Console.Write("{ ");
        foreach (var i in pair.Value)
        {
            Console.Write(i + " ");
        }
        Console.Write("}");
        return true;
    }
```

Not included is the linq function to get the largest key in the list which corresponds to the greatest value, something like:

```
 finalSet.OrderByDescending(x => x.Key).First();
```

I know that this isn't the best way to go about it, but i'd still like to ask what i'm doing wrong in the implementation.

Currently, it would print for the final set: 180, 1 3. When it should've been 220.

Comment: There are two alternatives to multidimensional arrays: 1. Jagged arrays. Personally I prefer them over multidimensional ones. 2. combine all indexes into a single index for a basic 1D array, wich would be really long. Counting a Chess/Checkers board as 100 squares, rather then 10x10 squares.